# Complex SQL command to raw Laravel 8

Tags: mysql, laravel-8

I'm new in Laravel and this is my first time with raw expressions because I need to use them because the SQL query I need to execute cant be done with Eloquent

```
select distinct idEspecialidad, case 
  WHEN fechaNacimiento  > '2011-01-01'  THEN '1-10' 
  WHEN fechaNacimiento > '2001-01-01' THEN '11-20'
  WHEN fechaNacimiento > '1991-01-01' THEN '21-30' 
  WHEN fechaNacimiento > '1981-01-01' THEN '31-40'
  WHEN fechaNacimiento > '1971-01-01' THEN '41-50'
  ELSE '50+' 
END as rangoEdades, count(*) as total  
from personas p, citas c
where c.idPersonaP = p.id 
group by rangoEdades, idEspecialidad
```

I'm trying to use it like this in Laravel

```
 $rangoEdades= DB::raw("distinct idEspecialidad, case
        WHEN fechaNacimiento  > '2011-01-01'  THEN '1-10'
        WHEN fechaNacimiento > '2001-01-01' THEN '11-20'
        WHEN fechaNacimiento > '1991-01-01' THEN '21-30'
        WHEN fechaNacimiento > '1981-01-01' THEN '31-40'
        WHEN fechaNacimiento > '1971-01-01' THEN '41-50'
        ELSE '50+'
      END as rangoEdades, count(*) as total
      from personas p, citas c
      where c.idPersonaP = p.id
      group by rangoEdades, idEspecialidad")->get();
```

The problem is that it says that I cant use the get with the query in Laravel.
What I need to change to be able to execute this Query with Laravel?

If you need more info of the code I can provide it.
The database is a MySQL database.

As requested a photo of the model
[image: Photo of model]

Script in console
[image: Script in console]

Comment: Can you include the `show create table personas`, `show create table citas` because we can't tell which table the columns are in. It looks doing a `group by` and a `distinct`. I suspect on of these is incorrect. Is this the complete set of results you are after? It looks like maybe you only need personas table.

Comment: The SQLquery works perfectly I can update the questiom to include the model and also the SQL when I use it in Dbeaver

Comment: @danblack placed picture of the model and what the Script gives me in console.

Comment: Ok. to clarify the `show create table` as text is preferred by most readers over images (for next time). Makes more sense now. I don't think you need a `distinct` as you are grouping  by the two fields so they are always `distinct`.

Comment: Ok then, sorry for that, I would keep that in mind for further questions. So then how I should modifiy the code in Laravel. Is the answer below by nbk right? @danblack  I need to get the resulta that are in the bottom of the second picture.

Comment: @nbk's Lavavel answer looks right. Just drop the 'distinct'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can rewrite your query to:

```
$rangoEdades= DB::table('personas AS p')
            ->join('citas c', 'c.idPersonaP', '=', 'p.id')
            ->selectRaw("distinct idEspecialidad, case
                         WHEN fechaNacimiento  > '2011-01-01'  THEN '1-10'
                         WHEN fechaNacimiento > '2001-01-01' THEN '11-20'
                         WHEN fechaNacimiento > '1991-01-01' THEN '21-30'
                         WHEN fechaNacimiento > '1981-01-01' THEN '31-40'
                         WHEN fechaNacimiento > '1971-01-01' THEN '41-50'
                         ELSE '50+'
                         END as rangoEdades, count(*) as total")
            ->groupByRaw('rangoEdades, idEspecialidad')
            ->get();
```